# Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: Response<Void> found Deferred<Response<Void>>

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

in my android app

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import retrofit2.Response
import java.util.*

   fun executeTraderOperation(traderOperation: Trader.Operation, base: String, quote: String): Response<Void> {
            lateinit var executeOperations: Response<Void>
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                executeOperations = async { runOperation(traderOperation, base, quote) }
            }
            return executeOperations
        }

        suspend fun runOperation(traderOperation: Trader.Operation, base: String, quote: String): Response<Void> {
            val traderMonitorRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TraderMonitorRestClient::class.java)
            val sender = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "_" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME
            val key = DateUtil.getDateAsString(Date(), "mmHHddMMyyyy")
            val executeTraderOperation = traderMonitorRestClient.executeTraderOperation(traderOperation.toString().toLowerCase(), base.trim(), quote.trim(), sender, key)
            val response = executeTraderOperation.await()
            return response
}
```

But I get **compile** error in this line:

```
executeOperations = async { runOperation(traderOperation, base, quote) }
```

error message:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required:
Response<Void>
found:
Deferred<Response<Void>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `async` returns that `Deffered`, drop it and transform that to:

```
async{
  val executions = runOperation(traderOperation, base, quote)
}
```

Comment: How I can  transform from Deferred<Response<Void> to Response<Void> ?

Comment: wrap it all to `async`